# How to toggle insert/replace mode when typing in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to enable the replace mode (aka overwrite aka overtype) for text editing in Google Colaboratory, so that characters to the right of the cursor are overwritten when I type?

In Jupyter Notebook **Insert** key works as supposed, but in Colab it does not, and I did not find it in hotkeys map or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a setting for it neither. But it seems like that happened to me when I zoom out the browser (I'm using Chrome). Perhaps you can try resetting it to 100%.